# Unity - Repaint/Redraw Scene after gameObject instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, redraw

**Unity**: 5.1.1f

**Language**: c#

When i instantiate a gameObject inside a Assets/Editor/ file, it doesn't appear in Scene until i select another scene's gameobject.

I've tried calling some methods like:

```
SceneView.RepaintAll();
HandleUtility.Repaint();
```

But non of them look to be working. This is how i spawn the object:

```
public class PrefabEditor: Editor {
    void OnSceneGUI() {
        GameObject prefabInstance = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;

        // assign him an icon label
        Texture2D tex = EditorGUIUtility.IconContent("sv_label_0").image as Texture2D;
        Type editorGUIUtilityType = typeof(EditorGUIUtility);
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        object[] args = new object[] {
            prefabInstance, tex
        };
        editorGUIUtilityType.InvokeMember("SetIconForObject", bindingFlags, null, null, args);

        EditorUtility.SetDirty(prefabInstance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using Editor class then instead of instantiate your gameObject like

```
GameObject prefabInstance = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

instantiate your gameObject like this

```
GameObject prefabInstance = (GameObject) PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
```

and try to use

```
SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.Repaint();
```

I hope this helps.